# Filament: Change default table names for imports

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, laravel-filament

I want to use the import records functionality mentioned here: https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/resources/creating-records#importing-resource-records

Although, I want to prefix the tables used in the import functionality in filament:

- job_batches -> mvl_job_batches
- notifications -> mvl_notifications
- imports -> mvl_imports
- failed_import_rows -> mvl_failed_import_rows

Also, the `user_id` columns in these tables needs to change -> `mvl_user_id`

As of now I've tried everything mentioned [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/filament/import-record-change-table-names?page=1&replyId=920681) . But I get an error: `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.imports' doesn't exist`

What all changes I need to make in order for the import to work successfully.